# LaTeX document with several margin settings

Tags: layout, latex

I am working on a latex document that needs two different margin settings.

The first part is a header that must have a 0.25in on both sides. It is made of an image and three to five text lines arranged in two columns.

Second part is the main body text with 1in in on both sides. This text can be several pages long.

The header is shown only on the first page.

Right after that header, the second part starts, in the same page. This second part is the document's main body.

I use the geometry page to set margins (for the header), but if write the header and then use \newgeometry command, the main text starts on the next page and I need to place them on the same one.

I do not want to use an image for the header as it will change often and I will create many documents with that structure.

Are there some way to create the document with the main text margins and create "an exception margin" just to insert the header on the same page? Suggestions are welcome :-D

I have tried the following:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

% This settings work for the header
\usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry}

% Dummy text generator
\usepackage{blindtext}

% Just to simulate logo
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
    % Document Header, first page only
    \begin{minipage}[t]{2in}
        \vskip0pt
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \fill [blue!30] (0,0) rectangle (1.75in, 1.5in);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{2.5in}
        \vskip0pt
        This is the first text block with some info about the company, department another stuff. It is only text.
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{3in}
        \vskip0pt
        This is a second text block with information about content creator, editor, etc. and it just text.
    \end{minipage}

    \hrulefill

    % Starting from here, I need narrow margins, about 1 inch on the left and right. The text must start right after the header
    % I have tried with \newgeometry{left=1in,right=1in} but the text starts on the new page.

    \section{First section}

    \blindtext

    \section{Second section}

    \blindtext

    Text, text and more text... several pages of text...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre] to give us something to start with

Answer (score 0):

Quick hack:

```
\documentclass{article}

% This settings work for the header
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

% Dummy text generator
\usepackage{blindtext}

% Just to simulate logo
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

  \centerline{%
   \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-0.5in\relax}
    % Document Header, first page only
    \begin{minipage}[t]{2in}
        \vskip0pt
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{2.5in}
        \vskip0pt
        This is the first text block with some info about the company, department another stuff. It is only text.
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{3in}
        \vskip0pt
        This is a second text block with information about content creator, editor, etc. and it just text.
    \end{minipage}%
    
    \hrulefill
   \end{minipage}
 }
 

    % Starting from here, I need narrow margins, about 1 inch on the left and right. The text must start right after the header
    % I have tried with \newgeometry{left=1in,right=1in} but the text starts on the new page.

    \section{First section}

    \blindtext

    \section{Second section}

    \blindtext

    Text, text and more text... several pages of text...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is it! Thank you so much, and thanks for the ducks. Yesterday I visited your stackoverflow profile and I discovered the ducks! Thanks again.

Comment: @RaúlUriarte You're welcome! And glad to hear that you like the ducks :)